# This code still has one warning in html code validator. What I still need to insert into it?

Tags: html

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

It seems I have a problem here:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">



<script type='text/javascript'>

function run(){
var div = document.createElement('div')
div.style.position = 'absolute'
div.style.left = '0px'
div.style.top = '0px'
div.onmouseover=function(){
    alert('mo')
    this.style.opacity = 0
}
div.style.width = '30px'
div.style.height = '30px';
div.style.backgroundColor = '#000'
document.body.appendChild(div)
}

onload = run
</script>
<title></title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

What do I still need to insert or edit, so my code becomes fully ok in code validator?
Thanks :)

Comment: What's the warning you're getting? A Warning is usually for "you don't have to fix it, but you should know it's there" kind of things.

Comment: The `body` element mustn't be empty.

Comment: tested in http://validator.w3.org/check by copy-paste. The warning only exists because its copy-paste so can't do utf8 check, not validating a real site.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Not true under the Transitional DTD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no problem with this code when dumped into the Validator using direct input

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

The one warning you get is

> Using Direct Input mode: UTF-8 character encoding assumed

which you can safely ignore.  It just means that UTF-8 is assumed on direct input.